# Undefined variable about the Uploader File with symfony2

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I am using  [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) for uploader Files with symfony2. When uploading a picture  i have a error :

> **ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: size in /home/../AdsBundle/Entity/Fileupload.php line 135**

**src/../Controller/AdminUploaderController.php**

> ```
> public function uploadtestAction() {
>     $f = new Fileupload();
>     $f->setName("why_use_linux.png");
>     $f->setPath("/home/ismail/Images/");
>     $f->setSize(1992894);
> ```
>
> ...
>       }

**src/../Entity/Fileupload.php**

> ```
> /**
>  * Set mimeType
>  *
>  * @param string $mimeType
>  * @return Fileupload
>  */
> public function setMimeType() {
>     $this->mineType = $mineType;
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

Is there any proposition to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide us the definition of your class to check the definition of the variable size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy my friend!

You just forgot to define your method `setSize()` with the parameter `$size`.
Redefine it as follows:

```
/**
 * Set size
 * @param decimal $size
 * @return Fileupload
 */
public function setSize($size) { // param missing here!
    $this->size = $size;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@aminejallouli **The definition of the class of the variable size :**

> ```
> /**
>  * @ORM\Column(name="size", type="decimal")
>  * @Gedmo\UploadableFileSize
>  */
> private $size;
>
>
> /**
>  * Set size
>  * @param decimal $size
>  * @return Fileupload
>  */
> public function setSize() {
>     $this->size = $size;
>     return $this;
> }
> /**
>  * Get size
>  *
>  * @return decimal 
>  */
> public function getSize() {
>     return $this->size;
> }
> ```